# Sorting Rows By Date Using Query in Google Sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

This query function is pulling the correct data, but for some reason its still not sorting the rows by date - any suggestions?

Copy of sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10LTLrb66F8t3jOPrvtuDs8wCrsSmNPcP953O_IWpjbM/edit?usp=sharing

```
=QUERY('Zapier Leads'!A2:AA, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, Z, AA, T, U, V, W, X, Y WHERE not A Matches 'selection8_address' order by 6 asc", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Kristan, to get the best response, please share a copy of your sheet - editable by all.  This lets us see exactly what you have, and how your data is structured.  I'm sure we can give you the answer you need, but using queries with dates can sometimes be tricky.

Comment: Just added the link to my sheet above to the original question - let me know your suggestions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned

> *...not sorting the rows by date*

The issue is that in your query formula at the `Master` tab you use `=QUERY('Zapier Leads'!A2:AA, "....",1)`
**This means that you consider the first row as a header**.
As a result cell `F2` is **NOT** formatted as Date.

Please use the following formula where the issue is fixed.

```
=QUERY('Zapier Leads'!A2:AA, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, Z, AA, T, U, V, W, X, Y WHERE A is not null and not A Matches 'selection8_address' order by F")
```

**In addition.**

For your `Last7DaysLeads` tab you can use this **simplified formula**.

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Filtered!A1:Z,"", 1), "WHERE Col24 > 10000 AND Col25 > 10000 order by Col6",1)
```

*Notice how we use `order by F` in the first formula, while `order by Col6` in the second.*

You can check your sheet to see the formulas in action.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are sorting by `6` instead of the date you want to.

Try here where you have `order by 6 asc` change it to where the column of the dates are: `order by (dateColumnNameHere) asc` or `order by 6, (dateColumnNameHere) asc`.

### Reference:

- [google query order by](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#order-by)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Tried adding "order by 6, 8/25/2020 asc" - still no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: in the "Zapier Leads" leads sheet, which is the name of the column where the dates are?

Comment: it will probably be a letter, like A or B (in the select), or `selection8_sale...` that is not possible to see in the image you shared

Comment: Gotcha, yes the name of Col6 is 'selection8_saleDate'. I made the change to "order by 6, 'selection8_saleDate asc'" it still gave me all the data, but the dates are STILL not ascending

Answer (score 1):

Having a copy of your sheet would make this easier, but from the statement in your question, you probably want the following.

```
=QUERY('Zapier Leads'!A2:AA, "SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, Z, AA, T, U, V, W, X, Y WHERE not A Matches 'selection8_address' order by F asc", 1)
```

Note the change of your `order by 6` to `order by F`, to indicate to sort by column F, assuming that is where your dates are.

However if the data in column F is not all in date format, you can get unexpected results.

Please let us know if this has helped, or if you still have an issue.